# Hide empty fields rows from html array jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to hide all those rows whose fields are empty using jquery.

Here is my Code DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/7k3y3/19/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">

    <div id="row_3">
        <input type="text" id="field_3" name="field[]" value="PHP"/>
    </div>  

    <div id="row_5">
        <input type="text" id="field_5" name="field[]" value="Javascript"/>
    </div>  


    <div id="row_8">
        <input type="text" id="field_8" name="field[]" value=""/>
    </div>  


    <div id="row_10">
        <input type="text" id="field_10" name="field[]" value="C++"/>
    </div>  


    <div id="row_12">
        <input type="text" id="field_12" name="field[]" value=""/>
    </div>      

</div>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="save">SAVE</a>
```

**JS :**

```
$(".save").click(function ()
    {
        var fieldArr = $( "input[name='field[]']" );

        for(i=1; i<=fieldArr.length;i++)
        {

            if(fieldArr[i]=='')
            {
                fieldArr[i].hide();    
            }

        }



    });
```

Comment: Use `class` instead of `name` in your HTML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write:

```
$(".save").click(function (){
    $("input[name='field[]']").each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == ""){
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/7k3y3/22/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".save").click(function (){
    $('.container :input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });                    
});
```

***[The demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/7k3y3/21/)***

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a DOM Element object with an empty string which is not true, of course, you should read the `.value` properties instead. Also you are calling jQuery `.hide()` method on a DOM element object, you should either use jQuery `.eq(i)` method which returns a jQuery wrapped element or manipulate the `style` property.

```
for (var i = 0; i < fieldArr.length; i++) {
    if (fieldArr[i].value == '') {
        fieldArr[i].parentNode.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Since you are using jQuery you can also use the `.filter()` method, which acts like a loop but only returns the elements that meet the condition, in this case values with length of 0:

```
$('.container > div').filter(function() {
    return !$("input[name='field[]']", this).val().length; 
}).hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GLeZc/

Answer (score 1):

This will work. Have tested it on fiddle.

```
$(".save").click(function(){
    $( "input[name='field[]" ).each(function(){ 
        if($(this).val() == ''){
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });              
});
```

Comment: EXACTLY COPIED FROM PREVIOUS ANSWER, First Posted 10mins before !

Comment: @BetaCoder He has tested it :)

Comment: @BetaCoder By the time I had run the code on fiddle and submitted here, Exactly similar answer was already posted :) Not my fault.